# Upgrade Django and NoReverseMatch password Error

Tags: python, django

I am trying upgrade old version Django 1.5 to newer.
And after upgrade when I go to password reset page, Django give me Error:

> **TypeError at /accounts/password/reset/**
>
> password_reset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_change_redirect'
>
> Request Method: GET
>   TypeErrorRequest URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/password/reset/
>   Django Version: 1.6.11
>   Exception Type: TypeError
>   Exception Value:
>
> password_reseteset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_change_redirect'
>
> Exception Location: /home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 99
>   Python Executable: /home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/bin/python
>   Python Version: 2.7.8

--

> Traceback:
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/eshopwisepress/wp_auth/views.py" in passwd_reset
>     109.     return password_reset(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in password_reset
>     142.         post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_done')
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
>     536.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
>     456.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
>
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/
>   Exception Value: Reverse for 'password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

In urls.py I have:

```
      url(r'^password/reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', name='passwd_reset_done'),
      url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>\w+)/(?P<token>[\d\w-]+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm_uidb36', name='passwd_reset_confirm'),
      url(r'^password/reset/completed/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete', name='passwd_reset_complete'),
      url(r'^password/reset/$', passwd_reset, {'template_name':'emailing/registration-activation/password_reset_email.html'}, name='password_reset'),
```

And in views.py I have:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset

def passwd_reset(request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['password_reset_form'] = PasswdResetForm
    kwargs['email_template_name'] = 'emailing/registration-activation/password_reset_email.html'
    kwargs['from_email'] = FROM_EMAIL
    return password_reset(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In Django 1.5 it works fine, but in newer versions give me the Error.
Do you know anybody how to fix it??
Thanks

**EDIT:**
I changed in urls.py some urls for reset password. Now is there:

```
    url(r'^password/reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^password/reset/completed/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete', name='password_reset_complete'),
    url(r'^password/reset/$', passwd_reset, {'template_name':'emailing/registration-activation/password_reset_email.html'}, name='password_reset'),
```

And now I have Error:

> **Template error:**
>   In template /home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/eshopwisepress/templates/emailing/registration-activation/password_reset_email.html, error at line 44
>
> ### >    Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': '', u'token': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/password/reset/confirm/(?P\w+)/(?P[\d\w-]+)/$']

**On line 44 is now:**

```
<a href="{{ protocol }}://{{ site_name }} {% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %} " target="_blank" style="color: #68b58e; text-decoration: none; font-style: italic;">Reset password</a><br/><br/>
```

--

> **Traceback:**
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     137.                 response = response.render()
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
>     105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
>     82.         content = template.render(context)
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>     140.             return self._render(context)
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
>     134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>     840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>     78.             return node.render(context)
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
>     447.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
>     433.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
>     536.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
>   File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
>     456.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
>
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/
>   Exception Value: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': '', u'token': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/password/reset/confirm/(?P\w+)/(?P[\d\w-]+)/$']

Comment: Can you post the entire traceback.

Comment: Traceback:
File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/eshopwisepress/wp_auth/views.py" in passwd_reset
  109.     return password_reset(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/martin/Work/wisepress.com/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: It's better to edit the question and add the traceback there, so you can format it nicely. I'm confused by the error message, because `post_change_redirect` is only used in the `password_change` method. Are you using the `password_change` and `password_change_done` views in your `urls.py`? Also, it might be a good idea to use the same url names as [Django uses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views), for example `name='password_reset_done'` instead of `name='passwd_reset_done'`.

Comment: traceback in better format: http://pastebin.com/n9hFgFxy

Comment: Ok I changed: name='password_reset_done' instead of name='passwd_reset_done'   And I also reloaded page and I now have new traceback, which I added to my post (I edited it).   I dont know, why there was  post_change_redirect  because in urls.py I dont see password_change or similar.

Comment: Can you update the urls.py in your question to match your current code?

Comment: Yes of course I updated it now

Comment: I changed the names and  uidb36 to uidb64. Now I have new error in template. More details are in my post which I updated.

Comment: You can simplify the template line to `{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`, but that doesn't explain your error.

Comment: In your [password_reset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) url pattern, the template name should not be the same as your email template name. The `template_name` is a template that shows the password reset form to the user.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I changed template_name to email_template_name and now it works :-)

Comment: Glad we got there in the end :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [`password_reset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) url pattern, the `template_name` should not be the same as your `email_template_name`. The `template_name` is a template that shows the password reset form to the user.